# How do you loop through a multiline string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, while-loop, loops

Pretty simple question from a first-time Ruby programmer.

How do you loop through a slab of text in Ruby? Everytime a newline is met, I want to re-start the inner-loop.

```
def parse(input)
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

[String#each_line](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_line)

```
str.each_line do |line|
    #do something with line
end
```

Answer (score 21):

What Iraimbilanja said.

Or you could split the string at new lines:

```
str.split(/\r?\n|\r/).each { |line| … }
```

Beware that `each_line` keeps the line feed chars, while `split` eats them.

Note the regex I used here will take care of all three line ending formats. `String#each_line` separates lines by the optional argument `sep_string`, which defaults to `$/`, which itself defaults to `"\n"` simply.

Lastly, if you want to do more complex string parsing, check out the built-in StringScanner class.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do with with any pattern:

```
str.scan(/\w+/) do |w|
  #do something
end
```

Answer (score -3):

```
str.each_line.chomp do |line|
  # do something with a clean line without line feed characters
end
```

I think this should take care of the newlines.

Comment: That won't work. String#each_line without a block returns an Enumerator, which doesn't respond to chomp. Beyond chomp doesn't take a block.

Comment: Something like `str.each_line.map(&:chomp).each do |line|...` would do that, but you might as well do it in the `each_line` iteration as a single pass.